# yii2 disable the rules if a checkbox is selected

Tags: yii2, rules, active-form

In the active form, I have 3 textinput and one checkbox.
All the 3 textinputs have rules that says cannot be empty. What I want is if the checkbox is clicked, It will disable the rules and will save the empty record in the database.

here is screen shot of the active form..

[image]

Comment: You can check the checkbox status and accordingly set the scenario for doing this

Comment: what do you mean by set the scenario? how do I do that?

Comment: Means specify 2 scenarios say 1) checked 2) notchecked. When the checkbox value is checked then set the scenarion as chekced and vice-versa. When checkbox value is unchecked then make the attributes compulsory by setting the scenario as "unchecked". Otherwise dont make them compulsary. Did you get it now?

Comment: I get your point. I can already determine if its checked or not.. I just dont know how to implement that using yii2 rules..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the rules that way (using [when](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail)):

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [            
        ['cancelled',   'boolean'],
        ['checkNumber', 'required'],
        ['payee',       'required', 'when' => function ($model) {return !$model->cancelled;}],
        ['particulars', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {return !$model->cancelled;}],
    ];
}
```

You may want to add [whenClient](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$whenClient-detail) as well to let the browser check this before it submits the form.

Comment: @nerison [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation) is an example.

Comment: I think you have given me the correct answer but I am using [link dynamic forms](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform#hypothetical-scenario) and I cant specify the ID of the checkbox. Do you have an idea on how to handle this in dynamic form?

Comment: @nerison No, unfortunately not. I'm not sure if it works with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$model = new SomeForm();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
if ($model->checkbox == true) $model->scenario = 'checked';
}
// your model rules:
[['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'safe', 'on' => 'checked']
```

or alternatively You can do this:

```
 if ($model->checkbox == true) $model->save(false); //this will disable any validation so be carefull
```

**edit:**
if You need cliend side validation switch, You have to use this:

```
[['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                return $model->cancelled == '0';
            }, 'whenClient' => new JsExpression("function (attribute, value) {  return $('#mailform-cancelled').val() == '0';}")]
```

Comment: This seems happen after the form is submitted. I want the browser check the validation first. Do you have an Idea to that?